# What files to watch with grunt-contrib-watch when wanting to reload Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I have an app written in Coffeescript.  My grunt.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    clean: {
      test: {
        files: [{
          src: ['.tmp']
        }]
      }
    },
    coffee: {
      compileScripts: {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        src: '*/*.coffee',
        dest: '.tmp/scripts',
        ext: '.js'
      },
    },
    jst: {
      compile: {
        files: {
          '.tmp/scripts/templates.js': ['scripts/**/*.ejs']
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      all: {
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          spawn: false
        },
        files: ['scripts/*.coffee', 'scripts/*.ejs', 'index.html'],
        tasks: ['compile'],
      }
    },
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          port: 8000,
          hostname: 'localhost',
          open: true,
          livereload: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jst');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

  grunt.registerTask('compile', ['clean', 'coffee', 'jst']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['compile', 'connect', 'watch']);
}
```

After much tinkering, I finally got the 'watch' working where my JS files are live reloading, but I'm not clear on what goes in the 'files' section of the watch task?  Did I do it right?

Do I have to watch the coffeescript files only?  Or do I also have to watch index.html so that if one of the coffeescript files change, the index.html will refresh and reload the new JS?  (All of my JS files are scripts in my index.html.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `files` property of the watch task contains a list of file patterns to watch and perform some action on when changed (most commonly run certain tasks).

The `tasks` property contains the tasks you want to run when the corresponding `files` have been changed.

Any target which has the `livereload` options configured on it will feed the `files` as they are changed to the live reload server. So if you have `*.coffee` files, they will be fed to the live reload server upon change. The live reload server only knows how to interpret js, css files so a `.coffee` file would refresh the entire page, instead of just the javascript.

The `tasks` property is optional with the watch task so a common solution to better configuring the live reload is this:

```
watch: {
  options: { spawn: false },
  all: {
    files: ['scripts/*.coffee', 'scripts/*.ejs'],
    tasks: ['compile'],
  },
  livereload: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    files: ['.tmp/**/*.{html,js,css}']
  }
},
```

So as your `compile` task runs it will trigger the `watch:livereload` target and live reload by feeding the correct files.

Regarding the `index.html`, in your instance you probably don't need to watch that file within the `watch:all` target. As it doesn't have any tasks that do any building from it (at least from the config I see above).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation, Kyle.  After all my reading, I still didn't understand how it worked, so now it is all making sense.  One problem I'm having...my index.html is just in the root directory (not under .tmp/), so when I add that to the 'files' under watch:livereload I would think that the index.html page would automatically refresh but it doesn't.  Is there something I am still not understanding?  If I manually refresh, my changes are properly displayed.  Just thought the page would refresh on its own.  I used your suggested script above in its entirety.